# WebStorm Jade compiling into HTML

Tags: html, pug, webstorm, indentation

I have a question about Jade compiling using WebStorm IDE.

How can I make it compile a jade file into html and keep the indentation?

That's how it compiles my code right now:

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `--pretty` option to Jade transpiler:

[image]